# Command for Bootstrapping a node with Roles and environment

Tags: chef-infra

I need to bootstrap a node.
How can I pass roles and environment while bootstrapping it?

Comment: There is a "environment" option on the knife bootstrap command (see knife help) and the roles can be specified as the run-list.

Answer (score 0):

`knife bootstrap -E whatever -r 'role[one],role[two]`.

In the future you can find information like this [in the documentation](https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html#options).